# PHP: set_include_path and require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, path, include, set

I got a problem with my php settings, I know that for sure 'cause the exact same lib works perfectly for my partner at HIS server.

```
$inc_path = get_include_path();
$inc_path .= PATH_SEPARATOR . "./rtmp" . PATH_SEPARATOR . "./SabreAMF";
set_include_path($inc_path);

require_once 'rtmp/SabreAMF/OutputStream.php';
require_once 'rtmp/SabreAMF/InputStream.php';
require_once 'rtmp/SabreAMF/AMF0/Serializer.php';
require_once 'rtmp/SabreAMF/AMF0/Deserializer.php';
require_once 'rtmp/SabreAMF/TypedObject.php';
```

and this is what I get

```
Warning: require_once(rtmp/SabreAMF/OutputStream.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\phpLoL-master\rtmp\RtmpClient.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'rtmp/SabreAMF/OutputStream.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear;./rtmp;./rtmp/SabreAMF;./rtmp;./SabreAMF') in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\phpLoL-master\rtmp\RtmpClient.php on line 7
```

Comment: Is `OutputStream.php` file present inside `SabreAMF` folder?

Comment: You are wrong in the way you are including , you just need to say require_once OutputStream.php

Comment: Because you PHP already knows that you your include path is $inc_path .= PATH_SEPARATOR . "./rtmp" . PATH_SEPARATOR . "./SabreAMF";

Comment: Yes, ofc... all the files are there

Answer (score 1):

Updating to php 5.4 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$inc_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    
require_once $inc_path.'/rtmp/SabreAMF/OutputStream.php';    
require_once $inc_path.'/rtmp/SabreAMF/InputStream.php';    
require_once $inc_path.'/rtmp/SabreAMF/AMF0/Serializer.php';    
require_once $inc_path.'/rtmp/SabreAMF/AMF0/Deserializer.php';    
require_once $inc_path.'/rtmp/SabreAMF/TypedObject.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are setting the include path

already like this

```
$inc_path .= PATH_SEPARATOR . "./rtmp" . PATH_SEPARATOR . "./SabreAMF";
set_include_path($inc_path);
```

Since now PHP knows that what ever file you are including might be in this path you can just include like below

```
require_once 'OutputStream.php';
```

or

```
require_once 'AMF0/Deserializer.php';
```

> NOTE : - I assume that you are doing set_include_path at your
>   application bootstrap , other wise this approach of set include path
>   pro grammatically wont work at all

Comment: The questing is, I think php suppose to have some settings that I can change for that code to work, because it is working on other php servers.

Comment: may be its not hapening at boot strap or you have not given read permissions to your files

Comment: I can change all the filed manually till it works, but I wanna know why it works at one system and not in the other.

Comment: How can I change the master directory, so require_once 'SabreAMF/AMF0/Const.php'; will work, cause the general folder is one before.

Comment: I am not actually getting what your problem is ,there are somany reasons for not getting included , and not getting accessed , your problem is in the deployment level , you have not deployed it properly , that is the problem , and also look into the apache logs carefully follow the application flow properly by using debug log and see where its breaking